# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated is deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am in the middle of trying to convert this app so I can use it in Xcode 5 and iOS7, it is saying dismissModalViewControllerAnimated is deprecated.

```
[self.navController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is read the UIViewController Class Reference.

Comment: Whenever you try to use a deprecated method, you should just open up the [method's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW30) in Xcode, and it will frequently tell you what the method's replacement is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new method is:

```
    [self.navController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO
                                           completion:nil];
```

The word modal has been removed

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: There is no such method.

Comment: @rdelmar Just edited my answer